# Cause: error=86, Bad CPU type in executable native android studio on m1 mac

Tags: android, apple-m1

I am using M1 MacBook Air and just installed native android studio and when I click on the run or build button, I get the following error

> 'Cause: error=86, Bad CPU type in executable' and '> Failed to transform core-1.5.0.aar (androidx.core:core:1.5.0) to match attributes {artifactType=android-compiled-dependencies-resources, org.gradle.status=release}.
> > Execution failed for AarResourcesCompilerTransform: /Users/tejaskulkarni/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/e759884e8e1539e68246ec4d8729cc98/transformed/core-1.5.0.
> > AAPT2 aapt2-7.0.0-7396180-osx Daemon #0: Daemon startup failed
> This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.'
> why ???

Comment: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/160004878

ADB has not been built for the ARM chip yet. You will need to run `softwareupdate --install-rosetta`